# Can I turn-OFF the warning that comes with maximizing the Tor window?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I realize it's an important notice so that people understand what anonymity they may be giving up by performing the action, but if I'm on a website that I've more or less accepted, and maybe even created a login and posted on (like this website) then I've already given up an amount of personal information such that also giving my screen size seems a bit insignificant.

The broadcast of my window size is something I'm not gong to forget.  Can I turn the incessant warning off?

I'll just double-click on top bar to minimize again, if I want to leave this site and get back to *super-stealth-mode* for additional surfing.

I'm at the current v.5.0.4.

Comment: ...and when you logged in to "real world" accounts and given some personal information, why you are using tor then?

Comment: @dummy - It is non of your business _why_ I use Tor.  : )

Comment: it is definitely not my business why you are using Tor! - i just wanted to point out, the more customizations you make the less effective TBB is working... and logging into real world account (or even if you just logged into a account once without Tor) you can be deanonymised!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy - You yourself are allowing temporary access (via NoScript) and Logging Into this website with a “real” email you have access to, as we as all who post here using Tor.  I do not think my _threat model_ requires me to hide my screen size since I've already identified myself.  Do you?  So once I'm on this site, I can F11 or double-click the top-bar to maximize, and I don't want to be told every time I'm a bad boy for doing it – but mostly I don't want the extra effort to clear the message _EVERY TIME_.  I won't do that, however, for general surfing.  Makin' sense now? - cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type: `About:config` in the address bar.

Search for the string: 
`extensions.torbutton.maximize_warnings_remaining`

Right-click it, and select 'edit', set the value to '0',
it will then list the parameter as 'user set',
next time you start tor browser and maximize it - it will not show the warning.